# Why does this numpy attribute suddenly become shared between instances

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, attributes, shared-ptr, instantiation

I stumbled upon odd behavior when using python 3.6 and numpy 1.12.1 under Linux.

I have an attribute `self.count` which I initialize with `np.array([0.0, 0.0, 0.0])`. I would expect that `self.count` would behave like any other attribute and have its own value per class instance.

However, in the code below, in the `addPixel` method when I use

```
self.count += (1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
```

the self.count attribute gets increased for all instances of the class `CumulativePixel`. I want to understand why this happens and why it's fixed when I do:

```
self.count = self.count + (1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
```

instead.

```
import numpy as np

class CumulativePixel(object):
    '''
    class adds rgb triples and counts how many have been added
    '''

    def __init__(self, rgb = (0,0,0), count=np.array([0.0, 0.0, 0.0]) ):
        '''
        Constructor
        rgb sum is stored as two values. The integer part plus float part
        they are stored in a 2x3 matrix where the first row are integer
        parts and the second row are float parts. The code always tries to 
        make sure that float part is below 1.0
        '''
        self.rgb = np.array( [np.fmod(rgb, (1,1,1)).astype(float), (rgb - np.fmod(rgb, (1,1,1)))] )
        self.count = count

    @staticmethod   
    #for now only works for positve numbers 
    def _pixeladdition (disassembled, rgb):
        disassembled += np.array( [np.fmod(rgb, (1,1,1)).astype(float), (rgb - np.fmod(rgb, (1,1,1)))] )

        fpart = np.fmod(disassembled[0], (1,1,1))
        overflowpart = disassembled[0]-fpart
        disassembled[0]=fpart
        disassembled[1]+=overflowpart

        return disassembled

    def addPixel(self, rgb):
        self.rgb = self._pixeladdition(self.rgb, rgb)     
        # += would globalize self.count into all instances! why ???
        self.count = self.count + (1.0, 1.0, 1.0)

    def getAvgPixel(self, multiply = (1.0, 1.0, 1.0), add = (0.0, 0.0, 0.0), roundpx = False):
        if 0.0 in self.count: return (0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
        averagepixel = np.sum(self._pixeladdition((self.rgb/self.count), add)*multiply, axis=0)

        if roundpx: averagepixel = np.round(averagepixel).astype(int)

        return averagepixel

    def getSums(self):
        return np.sum(self.rgb, axis=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return "count: " + str(self.count) + " integers: " + str(self.rgb[1].tolist())+ " floats: " + str(self.rgb[0].tolist())

    def __repr__(self):
        return "CumulativePixel(rgb = " + str(tuple(np.sum(self.rgb, axis=0))) + ", count=" + str(self.count) +")"
```

**Edit:**
I create instances of this class (in yet another class) as follows:

```
self.pixeldata = [CumulativePixel() for i in range(self.imagewidth*self.imageheight)]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common bug, most often seen when using a list as the default value for a function.

```
count=np.array([0.0, 0.0, 0.0])
```

This array is created once, when the class is initialized. So all instances share the same `create` attribute, same array.  They don't get a fresh array.

When you do `self.create +=...` you modify it in-place.

With `self.create = self.create + ...`, you create a new array, so the change in one instance doesn't affect the others.

It's good practice to do something like this:

```
 def __init__(self, create=None):
     if create is None:
        create = np.array([1,2,3,4])
     self.create = create
```

Now the default value will be fresh, unique for each instance.

Comment: I see, that's probably also the reason why so many libraries use None as default although the internal default value is actually often some specific value. It also reminds me of list multiplication ([object]*number) where you end up with multiple copies of identical pointer.